# How to query the number of Gemfire client connections?

Tags: gemfire

I'm trying to look up how many clients are connected to a Gemfire server at any given time. I found `currentClientConnections` in the [documentation](http://gemfire702.docs.pivotal.io/7.0.2/userguide/index.html#managing/statistics/statistics_list.html) but it's not clear on how to read this data. I tried running VMWare VSD, but it crashes on startup under Windows.

Any ideas how to access this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command-line worked for me:

`watch -n1 "gemfire stats -archive=logs/server/stats/gemfire_stats.gfs  | grep -i currentClientConnections"`

Meaning, it lists all statistics, only prints the value of `currentClientConnections`, and repeats the process every second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show metrics` command from GemFire Shell `gfsh` to get the currentClientConnections like so:

```
gfsh>show metrics --member=serv1 --port=40404
```

You can see currentClientConnections in the cache-server section of the output:

```
<snip>
cache-server  | clientConnectionCount            | 0
              | hostnameForClients               |
              | getRequestAvgLatency             | 0
              | putRequestAvgLatency             | 0
              | totalConnectionsTimedOut         | 0
<snip>
```

more information on `gfsh` can be found in the [documentation](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#tools_modules/gfsh/chapter_overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also access this information via JMX using JConsole or other JMX client. If you connect directly to the server node you can access that server's GemFire MBeans. If you connect to the GemFire JMX Manager node (the Locator by default) then you'll see the DistributedMXBean as well as the MemberMXBeans and CacheServerMXBeans for every server node.

```
+GemFire
    +Distributed [1]
        +System --> DistributedSystemMXBean [2]
            ...getNumClients() [3]
    +Member [4]
        +member1 --> MemberMXBean [5]
        +member2 --> MemberMXBean [5]
        +CacheServer
            +2090
                +member1 --> CacheServerMXBean [6]
                    ..getClientConnectionCount() [7]
            +2091
                +member2 --> CacheServerMXBean [6]
                    ..getClientConnectionCount() [7]

[1] these MBeans are viewable only in the JMX Manager (Locator by default)
[2] ObjectName is GemFire:service=System,type=Distributed
[3] returns the total number of client connections across the entire cluster 
(number of client connections, not the number of unique clients)
[4] these MBeans are viewable in each server node as well as federated in the JMX Manager (Locator by default)
[5] ObjectName is GemFire:type=Member,member={0}
[6] ObjectName is GemFire:service=CacheServer,port={0},type=Member,member={1}
[7] returns the number of client connections for this server
```